# preg_replace() in PHP - Replacing n-occurrences of a character with n-occurrences of another, when following a new line

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm looking to replace all occurrences of space characters that follow a new line (or occur at the beginning of the input string). I know that I can achieve this using preg_replace_callback() with a callback that uses str_repeat and strlen, or similarly with the /e switch; but was wondering if it could be done more simply.

Currently I have the following:

```
$testData = "  Hello\n to everybody\n   in the world";
echo preg_replace('/^|\n( )+/', '&nbsp;', $pValue);
```

which gives:

```
"&nbsp;  Hello&nbsp;to everybody&nbsp;in the world"
```

What I'm really after is:

```
"&nbsp;&nbsp;Hello\n&nbsp;to everybody\n&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;in the world"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have searched harder before asking: found the answer (for a java solution) that seems to work perfectly. I'll leave the solution here for the sake of anybody else that has the same problem.

```
$testData = "  Hello\n to everybody\n   in the world"; 
echo preg_replace('/(?m)(?:^|\\G) /', '&nbsp;', $pValue);
```

Now just need to identify whether older versions of PHP support this.

Comment: How much older?  The `preg_*` functions have always been powered by the PCRE library, and according to its changelog PCRE has supported `\G` since version 4.0, Feb/2003. ref: http://www.pcre.org/changelog.txt

Comment: @Alan - I wasn't familiar with the \G operator at all, and know that PHP has introduced access to a lot of new regexp elements/switches over time. This is for a performance boost, in an open source library: I'm mainly concerned with 5.2.0 (I won't generally provide support for earlier than that), but know that some users of the library are working with versions of PHP as early as 5.1.6

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion

```
$pValue = "  Hello\n to everybody\n   in the world";
echo myReplace($pValue);

function myReplace($value)
{
    $value = preg_replace('/(^|\\n)((&nbsp;)*) /', '\1\2&nbsp;', $value);
    if (preg_match('/(^|\\n)((&nbsp;)*) /', $value))
    {
        $value = myReplace($value);
    }
    return $value;
}
```